# Messages are not getting consumed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, azure-eventhub, spring-camel

I have added the below configuration in application.properties file of Spring Boot with Camel implementation but the messages are not getting consumed. Am I missing any configuration? Any pointers to implement consumer from Azure event hub using kafka protocol and Camel ?

```
bootstrap.servers=NAMESPACENAME.servicebus.windows.net:9093
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="{YOUR.EVENTHUBS.CONNECTION.STRING}";
```

The route looks like this:

```
from("kafka:{{topicName}}?brokers=NAMESPACENAME.servicebus.windows.net:9093" )
                .log("Message received from Kafka : ${body}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue. Since I was using the Spring Boot Auto configuration (camel-kafka-starter), the entry on the application.properties file had to be modified as given below:

```
camel.component.kafka.brokers=NAMESPACENAME.servicebus.windows.net:9093
camel.component.kafka.security-protocol=SASL_SSL
camel.component.kafka.sasl-mechanism=PLAIN
camel.component.kafka.sasl-jaas-config =org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="{YOUR.EVENTHUBS.CONNECTION.STRING}";
```

The consumer route for the Azure event hub with Kafka protocol will look like this:

```
from("kafka:{{topicName}}")
.log("Message received from Kafka : ${body}");
```

Hope this solution helps to consume events from Azure event hub in Camel using Kafka protocol